# Hadoop Use cases-User Interface

Tags: php, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop2

I have no idea of how do I connect my website (I'm not sure if even there is a possibility) with HDFS.

I have my website built on PHP.  I want to store the region where someone clicks on my website, how do I connect my PHP with HDFS?

Are there any plugins involved? And what if I want this information to be stored real-time?

I tried doing some research before posting it to SO but couldn't get much clear..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `HDFS` as data store, then `Apache HBase™` is the `Hadoop` `database`, a `distributed`, `scalable`, `big data store` and gives `realtime processing`.
`HBase` internally uses `HDFS` to store data.
It provides database operations like `put(), get(),delete()` to interact with it.
It supports `row level transactions` only as of current version.
Hope it helps!

Comment: How do I connect my PHP page with HBase? Any plugins?

Comment: Use this [link](http://www.developer.com/java/other/php-with-java-using-php-java-bridge-tutorial.html) for connecting